# Traversing node using xpath

Tags: xpath

How do I write xpath query for the node below? I need to traverse the tree until child `"Attribute"` is not null.

```
<Attribute name="ParentNode" type="collection" datatype="collection" value="">
   <Attribute name="ChildNode" type="collection" datatype="collection" value="">
     <Attribute name="GrandChild" type="Measurable.Text" datatype="string" value="2605"/>
   </Attribute>
</Attribute>
```

Comment: Do you mean until there are no more `Attribute` children? Are you looking for the `Attribute` leaf node?

Comment: until there are no more Attribute children

Comment: So you actually mean traverse the tree until there is NO child Attribute element. You should correct your question to make that clear: not null isn't an accurate description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath expression: `//Attribute[not(*)]`.